# Should I install multiple network services on single VM?

Tags: linux, security, performance, esxi

I have a **ESXi** installed on **Dell Poweredge T110 II**. On this computer, I'm runing multiple VM.
At the moment, there are multiple network services on multiple VMs.
For example: I have `DNS,VPN,Git` on one, `LAMP stack` on other, `email services(Postfix)` on third and so on.

**My question is**: Is this good practice? Or should I install each network service on seperate VMs? If not, which services can be used together?

I've heard that seperation services can greatly increase security. Is this correct?

P.S: System resources are not an issue and I can afford to run each service individually.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: separate VM's , one for each service improves security and reliability. you need to have the hardware for that ofc.

Comment: As with many questions like this, the answer is "it depends".  tell us more about your environment (Home, small bus, etc) and whether you have regulatory requirements (HIPAA, SOX) and we can help fine tune the response.  Keep in mind, one can always make it "more secure", but you have to draw a line somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's for small business. My enviroment isone server on which there are many VMs. My biggest concern is that sepearte services mean more server to administrate. I'm basicaly a student that was thrown into system administration out of necessity. I could always use clusters to administrate more servers, right? Thanks again